# Image overflows fixed-height flex container

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I'm using a fixed-height flex container to do the layout. In the container, there are three components: header, content, footer. I want to force the content to use the rest of the height (i.e. content height = fixed-height minus header and footer). In my content, it will include an image and some texts.

However, the image always overflows a fixed-height flex container even providing max-height: 100% to constrain the height, but I want to put header, content, and footer into a fixed flex container.

Does anyone know how to fix it?

code: https://codepen.io/mrchung402/pen/wvGPJxz

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="header">
     header
  </div>
  <div class="content"> 
    <div class="my-img">
      <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/274x295">
    </div>
    <div class="my-text">
      my-text
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="footer">
    footer
  </div>
</div>
```

```
.container {
  border: solid 1px red;
  display: flex;
  max-width: 500px;
  height: 200px;
  flex-direction: column;
}
.header {
  flex: 0 0 auto;
  background: #A7E8D3;
}
.content {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
.footer {
  flex: 0 0 auto;
  background: #D7E8D4;
}
.my-img {
  max-height: 100%;
  height: auto;
  max-width: 100%;
}

img {
  max-height: inherit;
  height: inherit;
}

.my-text {
  background: #C7A8D4;
}
```

[image: img overflows flex item]

Comment: `.container{ height: 200px; }`. What do you expect?

Comment: i expect header, content, and footer will not exceed the container

Comment: Not if you want to fit your image in there too.

Comment: delete `height: 100vh` from `.container`. @StackSlave told you right.

Comment: what i want is to put all flex items into a flex container with heights: 200px

Comment: Well, that's impossible. unless you give your `my-img` a ` max-height: 150px;` since you are using fixed height. Or just remove the fixed hight of the class `.container` and it will fit.

Comment: i see. can you explain why this not works? I think  `max-height: 100%` should constrain the height for an image

Comment: Just don't give the container a height at all, and if it's `block` level or `inline-block` it should automatically stretch to fit the contents, if you haven't `float`ed the container.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of styling `.my-img` you should style `.my-img img`

```
.my-img img{
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}
```

Comment: i think it will not affect the layout even do so?